# I want to use `layout false` but I still want to use the CSS that would typically load when I'm rendering the layout - how do I do this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, layout, asset-pipeline

I have a controller where I set layout to false:

```
class SplashController < ApplicationController
  layout false
  def index
  end
end
```

But when I load this page there is no css whatsoever - I assume this has to do with how rails handles `layout false` - but my current knowledge of rails leaves me lost.

How do I not render a layout, but still load all the other assets (css, js, etc. . .) that would typically load if I were to load a layout?  (*Note that the layout file has no specific reference to any of these assets)

Comment: Setting layout to false will not display the page so why the need of css, js assets?

Comment: I was using layout false to allow the rest of the information to be displayed and just not use the layout around the information.  Is this not good practice to accomplish what I'm trying to do?  Specifically I'm having difficulty referencing a layout from within an engine and would rather just have no layout as a quick fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, if you use the `:text` option, the text is rendered without using the current layout. If you want Rails to put the text into the current layout, you need to add the :layout => true option.

As you need only the information to be displayed, I suggest to use `:text` to render.

You can send plain text – with no markup at all – back to the browser by using the :text option to render:

```
render :text => "OK"
```

NOTE: Rendering pure text is most useful when you’re responding to AJAX or web service requests that are expecting something other than proper HTML.

UPDATE:

Also if you want that assets should be shown but still layout should be false then you have to render layout to false after making the assets available. This means you make some view, then define your required css and js files there and then call that view from controller and then set layout to false.

Setting the layout to false after view will show the css and js stuff but still keep the layout to false.

But setting the layout to false before showing the view that contains css and js will not include assets at all.

The other alternative of the above will work also:

```
css : <%= eval("render :partial => 'myurl/blah', :formats=> [:css], :layout => false").dump.html_safe %>
```

You see that how partial view that contains your assets like `:css` is getting called while layout is false.

Comment: I don't understand where `css : <%= eval("render :partial => 'myurl/blah', :formats=> [:css], :layout => false") %>` would actually be placed.  In the view somewhere?

Comment: Yes you have to place it in your view.